# Power BI CosmosDB Flattening table

Tags: powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

I'm following this tutorial exactly:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powerbi-visualize

But when I do step 2 of the "Flattening and transforming JSON documents" section I do not see the field names for the dataset. I only see:

```
$t
$v
id
_self
_etag
_rid
_attachments
_ts
```

I have tried clicking display all, but it's still the same set of fields.

Comment: So... do you definitely see the list of rows with just the one field 'Document' and then click the expander?  It sounds like  you have selected the wrong elements -- just check the boxes in front of the listed fields (Volcano Name, Country, Region, Location, Elevation, Type, Status and Last Know Eruption)

Comment: Yep it's at that higher level. I take it you don't get this issue then? Am using the latest version of Power BI in case that matters.

Comment: I'm not actually connecting thru Azure Cosmos DB tho -- just reading the file through the JSON connector.  So, might not be a valid comparison.

Comment: I believe it's related to this: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-t-read-from-Azure-Cosmos-DB-because-ObjectId/td-p/399013  Will have to look into it in more detail later though.

Comment: Further update - my colleague tells me it's to do with the fact we are using CosmosDB in Mongo API model which is not really supported by Microsoft when it comes to Power BI compatibility